# (node:18768) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku?

Tags: heroku

Is it posible to modifiy the config.json to solve this heroku error?

I'm getting this error from heroku:

```
(node:18768) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: 
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 72
```

and i'm not sure if I should change the file content and add the } that is missing or if may get into big trouble and mess the whole thing:

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "5103b005-d953-4bce-8c79-2af625dee7a6"
}
 "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 1 open bracket and 2 closed brackets. `skipAnalytics` needs to be brought inside the brackets or else you'll get the JSON parse error you're seeing there.

Comment: Well, that is one of the many posibilities. May be I should change with a , the } in "5103b005-d953-4bce-8c79-2af625dee7a6"
}
 "skipAnalytics": false

Comment: I have deleted the file C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json and run heroku addons (just by chance) and it has created a new one without the error (with a comma).

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I am not sure what you did regarding Heroku addons to fix your problem.  However, I changed the } to a , and this stopped the error.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the contents of that file at

```
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json.
```

Its syntax is wrong already. This should work:

```
{
    "schema": 1,
    "install": "a91a785d-46db-466f-b0a3-93c3e2ea3e9d",
    "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

(node:18768) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku?

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "5103b005-d953-4bce-8c79-2af625dee7a6"
}
 "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

So, what i did to fix this was simple and here it is below:

```
{
  "schema": 1,
  "install": "a91a785d-46db-466f-b0a3-93c3e2ea3e9d",
  "skipAnalytics": false
}
```

> That fixed it for me, this should be of great help to someone